# Using "fread", how to eliminate comment line from csv?

Tags: r, csv, comments, fread

I have to read a CSV file which has some comment lines(start with #) along with data rows. `fread` function is used to read this CSV file.

```
config <- fread("Configuration.csv")
```

[image: CSV file snapshot]

In this file number of lines are not fixed they might be changed. How to read the CSV without these comment lines.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Apparently, `fread` doesn't have a `comment.char` argument for your purpose. The `base` `read.csv` and similar functions have it. Either you use `read.table` or you use `fread`, read all the lines and remove them afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to clean the data using grep before, not after:

```
config <- fread("grep -v '^#' Configuration.csv")
```

**UPDATED:**

If the aim of using fread() is to convert the data to data.table only, you can use read.table() instead with default comment.char="#" and then convert the result into data.table:

```
config <- as.data.table(read.table(header = TRUE, "Configuration.csv"))
```

Comment: This I guess is the only way if one wants to stick with `fread`. Unfortunately, it might not be portable, since it relies on shell commands.

Comment: Yes,  this version depends on system commands. The aim was to minimize the RAM size required.

Comment: fread is similar to read.table but faster and more convenient

Answer (score 2):

## updated answer

I assume you are using windows... if so, you can feed the results from [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) to `fread()`.
The data from the orinal answer is saved to `test.csv`.

```
data.table::fread( cmd = 'findstr "^[^#]" test.csv', sep = "\n", header = FALSE )

#                V1
#1:  line,with,data
#2: line2,with,data
```

`findstr /b /v test.csv` gives the same result

When on linux, you can (probably) pass the output from a `grep` command to `fread()`.

## old answer

This sulution is not very helpful when dealing with only one file, but is will help when reading in multiple files using `lapply()`

```
text = "line,with,data
#commentline,with,data
line2,with,data"

data.table::fread( text, sep = "\n", header = FALSE )[!grepl( "^#", V1 )]
```

Comment: @RonakShah see updated answer for a 'real' solution that filters the file before passing results to fread.

Comment: As I said in the other answer, using some shell command might be the only way if one wants to stick with `fread`. On the other hand, using shell commands is a bad practice since make your code not portable.