# R reading certain column values from multiple csv's

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, tidyverse

I got multiple csv files in my folder which follows the following sintax:
"Sales-"Month"-"Year"

For eg:

```
Sales-APR-2019.csv 
Sales-APR-2020.csv 
Sales-MAR-2019.csv 
Sales-DEC-2019.csv
```

My task in R is to extract certain products for all of 2019. I set my function as the following:

```
myfiles = list.files( pattern="SALES-EXTRACT-...-2019-NEW.csv", full.names=TRUE) \
file <- ldply(myfiles, read_csv)
```

Here's the catch, the files are big so I don't want to load them all into R. If I have the articles I need for example 1,2,3,4 and 5, how can I specify to only fetch where the column values are equal to those articles?

Lastly I would like to omit the reading the first line of all csv's which 1 file would be read like: \

```
file <- read.csv("SALES--APR-2019.csv",header = TRUE)[-1,]
```

where in the code can I specify the [-1,] when reading all of the files?

Comment: You can also choose to preprocess with `findstr` (windows) of `grep` (linux) and read the results using `data.table::fread()`. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568068/using-fread-how-to-eliminate-comment-line-from-csv/55568405

Answer (score 1):

The [vroom package](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) provides a 'tidy' method of selecting / dropping columns by name during import. Docs: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/#column-selection

##### Column selection (col_select)

The vroom argument 'col_select' makes selecting columns to keep (or omit) more straightforward. The interface for col_select is the same as dplyr::select().

Select columns by name

```
data <- vroom("flights.tsv", col_select = c(year, flight, tailnum))
#> Observations: 336,776
#> Variables: 3
#> chr [1]: tailnum
#> dbl [2]: year, flight
#> 
#> Call `spec()` for a copy-pastable column specification
#> Specify the column types with `col_types` to quiet this message
```

Drop columns by name

```
data <- vroom("flights.tsv", col_select = c(-dep_time, -air_time:-time_hour))
#> Observations: 336,776
#> Variables: 13
#> chr [4]: carrier, tailnum, origin, dest
#> dbl [9]: year, month, day, sched_dep_time, dep_delay, arr_time, sched_arr_time, arr...
#> 
#> Call `spec()` for a copy-pastable column specification
#> Specify the column types with `col_types` to quiet this message
Use the selection helpers
data <- vroom("flights.tsv", col_select = ends_with("time"))
#> Observations: 336,776
#> Variables: 5
#> dbl [5]: dep_time, sched_dep_time, arr_time, sched_arr_time, air_time
#> 
#> Call `spec()` for a copy-pastable column specification
#> Specify the column types with `col_types` to quiet this message
```

##### To load multiple files and select specific columns and skip the first line:

```
files <- fs::dir_ls(glob = "SALES*2019.csv")
data <- vroom(files, col_select = c(article_1, article_2, article_3, etc), skip = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the articles information is stored in a column called `article` in each file you may try -

```
library(tidyverse)

keep_articles <- 1:5
myfiles = list.files(pattern="SALES-.*-2019.csv", full.names=TRUE)

data <- map_df(myfiles, ~read_csv(.x) %>% 
                  slice(-1) %>%
                  filter(article %in% keep_articles), .id = 'file')
```

`data` would have one combined dataframe reading all the csv's and keeping rows for `keep_articles`. Also an additional `file` column would be created to distinguish between the rows of different files.