# How to import multiple .csv files from folder into R and select columns?

Tags: r

I have a folder in my computer with 27 different .csv files. Each file is a brazilian state and it’s hospitalization data.

I want to import those files into R and make a single dataframe with the 27 files.

Is there any way I can import all those files as one dataframe but only select the columns/variables that I want? Cause each file has over 200 variables, but I’ll only need to work with 10 of them.

All files together have over 16GB. I don’t think my computer will be able to read that.

Thanks.

Comment: This approach may be suitable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68524573/12957340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this approach -

```
#column names
cols <- c('col1', 'col5', 'col6', ...)
#Or column numbers
#cols <- c(1, 5, 6, ...)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

all_files <- list.files('/csv/folder', pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
result <- map_df(all_files, 
            ~.x %>% readr::read_csv() %>% select(cols), .id = 'filenum')

result
```

In `result`, I have also created an additional column called `filenum` which will indicate the file number from where the row is originating.

Comment: don't you need to wrap `.x` in a call to `readr::read_csv()` or `data.table::fread()`??

Comment: Where "'/csv/folder'" is I should put my directory, right? It's not working, says that R "Can't subset columns that don't exist", but all files have the same variable names.