# how to specific col_type when using read_delim with map_dfr?

Tags: r, purrr, readr

I am trying to combine several txt files into one dataframe while importing them. I used the below code but it threw up mismatch since one of the columns was interpreted to be double in certain files and character in others. Could someone please help me sort this out?

```
read_files <- fs::dir_ls(folder_path)%>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(read_delim,.id="source")
```

When I pass col_types to read_delim I get argument "file" missing error.

```
read_files <- fs::dir_ls(folder_path)%>% # returns file names as named path
  map_dfr(read_delim(col_types = list(BUSINESS_UNIT = col_character())),.id="source")
```

and if I pass (.) as the first argument for read_delim then I get below error,

Can't convert `.f`, a <spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame> object, to a function.

Comment: I use [vroom](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) for this, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68524573/12957340. Would that suit your use-case?

Comment: @jared_mamrot read_delim seems to be using vroom, the full error I receive for the second code snippet is as follows  Error in vroom::vroom(file, delim = delim, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types,  : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default

Comment: Do you get your required output using `read_files <- fs::dir_ls(folder_path); df <- vroom::vroom(read_files, delim = delim, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types, id = "source")`? The `vroom()` command can do the 'map_dfr'-ing and the 'source' column for you.

Comment: @jared_mamrot thank you. Yes, I get the required output using your code.

Comment: Sorry my first comment wasn't very clear; glad you solved your problem :)